# Millimetric grid under PGFPlots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to recreate a plot that I found on a book for my students. The plot has a grid (1 mm x 1 mm) and above it, the axis and the function graph.

I'm having trouble creating the grid, which has some emphasis every 5 mm. I assume I have to use `minor grid style` and `major grid style` to set the colors for the grid and it's emphasis.

So, how can I set the grid to have 1 mm by 1 mm divisions? I'd like to point out that setting "ticks" give me little black lines on the axis, which I do not want, only the grid.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} %Para fazer desenhos
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}    [
axis lines = {center},
%width = {0.6\linewidth},
ylabel = {$y$},
xlabel = {$x$},
ytick distance = {2},
xtick distance = 1,
ymin=-1,
ymax=11,
xmin=-0.9,
xmax=4.9,
major grid style={gray},
minor grid style={lightgray},
grid=both
]

\addplot    [
mark = none, domain= -1:5, smooth %samples at = {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}
]
{x^2 -5*x + 6};

\addplot    [
mark=*
]
coordinates {(2.5,-0.25)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the image I'm trying to base myself on. I know the function in the MWE isn't the same as the image, but it's just a reference for the grid. My idea is to have some examples of functions and also some instances with only the axis and grid, so the students can build the plots:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as pure `tikz` picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% grid
\draw[     thin,brown!25]   (-2,-2) grid[step= 1mm] ++ (8,15);
\draw[semithick,brown!50]   (-2,-2) grid[step= 5mm] ++ (8,15);
\draw[    thick,brown!75]   (-2,-2) grid[step=10mm] ++ (8,15);
% axis
\draw[-Stealth] (0,-1) -- (0,11) node[below right] {$y$};
\draw[-Stealth] (-1,0) -- (5, 0) node[below  left] {$x$};
\foreach \i in {1,...,4}{\draw (\i,1mm) -- + (0,-2mm) node[below] {\i};}
\foreach \i in {2,4,...,10}{\draw (1mm,\i) -- + (-2mm,0) node[ left] {\i};}
% curve
\draw[very thick, red]  plot[domain= -1:5] (\x, \x*\x - 5*\x + 6);
\draw                   plot[mark=*]    coordinates {(2.5,-0.25)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here an answer with `pgfplots`, three grid levels and the ticks removed:

In order to get a proper mm grid, you have to set the x- and y-vector to a fixed value, thus disabling auto scaling (`x=1cm,y=1cm`). Here 1cm is needed for the major grid. The minor grid is set by defining the number of ticks between 2 major ticks using `minor x tick num=9` and `minor y tick num=9`.

`pgfplots` only offers two grid levels, but a third can be drawn manually. This requires to enable layers in order to draw the middle grid below the axis (done with `\pgfplotsset{set layers=standard}`). The `\draw` command has then to be put in `\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid} ... \end{pgfonlayer}`. In order to make the middle grid work for graph paper without plots, two `\foreach` loops are used.

If you want only the graph paper, just leave out the plots (i.e. no `\addplot`).

The ticks can be removed with `\pgfplotsset{every major tick/.style={draw=none}, every minor tick/.style={draw=none}}`.

I also took the freedom to make the axes thicker.

Here the result:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
%\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot} %Para fazer desenhos
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,shapes.geometric,calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations,babel,patterns,fit}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    % style for middle grid
    middle grid style/.style={lightgray,line width=0.5pt}
]
\pgfplotsset{%
    % enable layer, needed to draw middle grid below axis
    set layers=standard,
    % disable ticks
    every major tick/.style={draw=none},
    every minor tick/.style={draw=none},
}
\begin{axis}    [
axis lines = {center},
% set fixed scale to get mm grid
% note: this is for the major grid
x=1cm,
y=1cm,
ylabel = {$y$},
xlabel = {$x$},
ytick distance = 1,
xtick distance = 1,
% number of minor ticks between 2 major ticks
minor x tick num=9,
minor y tick num=9,
ymin=-1,
ymax=11,
xmin=-0.9,
xmax=4.9,
major grid style={lightgray,thick},
minor grid style={lightgray,very thin},
grid=both,
% optional stuff
% change axis line width
axis line style={thick},
% make tick labels cover the grid
%ticklabel style={inner sep=1pt,fill=white},
]

% draw middle grid
\begin{pgfonlayer}{axis grid}
% works only for x=y=1cm with plots
%\draw[middle grid style,step=0.5cm]
%    (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) grid
%    (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
% to be used for graph paper with no plots (and if x != y)
%               v-- first, second and last x-positions for middle grid
\foreach \x in {-0.5,0.5,...,4.5}{
    % \edef-trick, see manual page 541
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[middle grid style]
        (axis cs:\x,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
        (axis cs:\x,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});}
    \temp
}
%               v-- first, second and last y-positions for middle grid
\foreach \y in {-0.5,0.5,...,10.5}{
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[middle grid style]
        (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\y) --
        (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},\y);}
    \temp
}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\addplot    [
mark = none, domain= -1:5, smooth %samples at = {-1,0,1,2,3,4,5}
]
{x^2 -5*x + 6};

\addplot    [
mark=*
]
coordinates {(2.5,-0.25)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a few parameters to the `axis` environment:

```
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = {center},
    %width = {0.6\linewidth},
    ylabel = {$y$},
    xlabel = {$x$},
    ytick distance = 2,
    xtick distance = 1,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=11,
    xmin=-0.9,
    xmax=4.9,
    grid=both,
    % here's what I changed/added:
    grid style={line width=.1pt,draw=lightgray},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray},
    minor tick num=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    tick style={draw=none},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
  ]
```

The result is now close enough to your book:

[image: result]

Notice that the units in your axes are differently sized; this is because of your tick distances.

Answer (score 0):

An answer with tikz and its plot command (I found that is more flexible than pgfplot's: `addplot`) Be careful with last `scale` that changes the function. You can use `yscale` or `xscale` too. Also a name of a defined color in the plot command, may be usefull.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Grid (with grid command):

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[step=1mm,color=orange,very thin] (-5 cm,-3cm) grid (5cm,3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


Custom Grid (with foreach command):

\xdef\xmin{-5}
\xdef\xsec{-4.9}
\xdef\xmax{5.01}
\xdef\ymin{-3}
\xdef\ysec{-2.9}
\xdef\ymax{3.01}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {\xmin,\xsec,...,\xmax} {
        \draw [thin,orange] (\x,\ymin) -- (\x,\ymax);
    }
    \foreach \y in {\ymin,\ysec,...,\ymax} {
        \draw [very thin,orange] (\xmin,\y) -- (\xmax,\y);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\pagebreak


Grid+Axes (with grid command):

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[step=1mm,color=orange,very thin] (-5 cm,-3cm) grid (5cm,3cm);
    \draw[-latex] (-4.5,0)--(4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}


Custom Grid+Axes (with foreach command):

\xdef\xmin{-5}
\xdef\xsec{-4.9}
\xdef\xmax{5.01}
\xdef\ymin{-3}
\xdef\ysec{-2.9}
\xdef\ymax{3.01}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {\xmin,\xsec,...,\xmax} {
        \draw [thin,orange] (\x,\ymin) -- (\x,\ymax);
    }
    \foreach \y in {\ymin,\ysec,...,\ymax} {
        \draw [very thin,orange] (\xmin,\y) -- (\xmax,\y);
    }
    \draw[-latex] (-4.5,0)--(4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\pagebreak

Grid+Axes+Plot (with grid command):

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[step=1mm,color=orange,very thin] (-5 cm,-3cm) grid (5cm,3cm);
    \draw[-latex] (-4.5,0)--(4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[domain=-2.1:2.1,variable=\x] plot ({\x},{\x*\x-2}); %y=x^2-2
\end{tikzpicture}


Custom Grid+Axes+Plot (with foreach command):

\xdef\xmin{-5}
\xdef\xsec{-4.9}
\xdef\xmax{5.01}
\xdef\ymin{-3}
\xdef\ysec{-2.9}
\xdef\ymax{3.01}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \x in {\xmin,\xsec,...,\xmax} {
        \draw [thin,orange] (\x,\ymin) -- (\x,\ymax);
    }
    \foreach \y in {\ymin,\ysec,...,\ymax} {
        \draw [very thin,orange] (\xmin,\y) -- (\xmax,\y);
    }
    \draw[-latex] (-4.5,0)--(4.5,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[left] {$y$};
    \draw[domain=-1:4,variable=\x,scale=0.5] plot ({\x},{\x*\x-3*\x+1}); %y=x^2-3x+1
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]