# graph with customised grid and tick

Tags: tikz-pgf

Latex users,

I want to create a set of axes filled with fine grid suitable for sketching graphs on, like the graph shown below. I also want to put labels on both x and y axes.

[image: what I want]

But with the code I have the x ticks and y ticks misalign with the grid.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{theorem}{THEOREM}
\newtheorem{proof}{PROOF}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
%\pagecolor{blue!13}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\voffset = 0.1cm
\pagestyle{fancy}
\definecolor{web}{RGB}{56, 102, 166}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
%grid=major,
xmin=-0.3,
xmax=10.8,
ymin=-0.6,
ymax=10.8,
height=9cm,
width=12cm,
%xtick={0,1.2,...,9.6,12},
%xticklabel={0,1,...,8,10},
%ytick={0,1,...,9,10},
%tick style = {line width = 0.1pt},
%tick style={very thick},
%tick style={very thick},
%enlargelimits=false,
%grid=both,
%axis line style={shorten >=-10pt, shorten <=-10pt},
%xlabel style={
%   anchor=west,
%   at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
%   xshift=10pt
%},
%xlabel=\text{NZD(\$)},
xtick={0,1.265,2.53,3.795,5.06,6.325,7.59,8.855,10.12,11.385,12.65},
xticklabels={$0$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$8$,$9$,$10$}
%ylabel style={
%   anchor=south,
%   at={(ticklabel* cs:1.0)},
%   yshift=10pt
%},
%ylabel=\text{AUD}(\$),
]
\draw[step=0.245cm,gray!50,very thin,opacity=0.9] (axis cs: 0,0) grid (axis cs: 10,10);
%\addplot[ultra thick,samples=100,domain=0:1] {0};
\node at (axis cs: -0.15, -0.3) {$O$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this is the resulting graph from the code:

[image: inccorrect graph]

Could you please suggest any modification so I get the desired output?

Many thanks

Comment: Just for curiosity: are you interested in the pgfplot features at all, or are you really just aiming at sketches? In other words, are you sure if you want to use an `axis` environment, and if so, why do you paint the grid "by hand"?

Comment: It’s a test question design - I do want to have a straight line graph through the origin and ask students to drive the equation of the line off the graph.

Comment: Very nice. But this doesn't answer my question. What I' implicitly saying is that you don't need `pgfplots` in order to draw a line on a grid. (BTW, when they drive a equation, do they need a driver's license? -- just kidding ;-)

Comment: Here are some answers that I suppose you are looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/398396/120578

Comment: @WillKim, is it a duplicate with the above question? Did you found a solution there?