# Indicating point on a graph with a given interval

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have drawn a graph ,but is there a simple way for indicating the points on a graph when an interval is given

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\width{6}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\hauteur{12}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
 \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, transform shape,linecolor/.style={thick,blue!80}linecolor/.style={ultra thick,blue}]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\incrmnt}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{5}
  \tikzset{help lines/.style={color=blue!80}}
\draw[thick,step=1cm,help lines] (-2,-2) grid (19,22);
\draw[ultra thick,step=5cm,help lines] (-2,-2) grid (19,22);
\draw[ thin,step=.2cm,help lines,blue!50] (-2,-2) grid (19,22);
% Draw axes
{\foreach \x in {4}
    \foreach \y in {8}
      {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.15cm);
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (0.05cm);
      }}
      {\foreach \x in {6}
    \foreach \y in {10}
      {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.15cm);
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (0.05cm);
      }}
      {\foreach \x in {8}
    \foreach \y in {12}
      {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.15cm);
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (0.05cm);
      }}
      {\foreach \x in {10.1}
    \foreach \y in {14}
      {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.15cm);
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (0.05cm);
      }}
      {\foreach \x in {12.1}
    \foreach \y in {16}
      {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.15cm);
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (0.05cm);
      }}
      {\foreach \x in {14.1}
    \foreach \y in {18}
      {
        \draw (\x,\y) circle (0.15cm);
        \fill (\x,\y) circle (0.05cm);
      }}
      \draw(0,4)--(16,19.78);
       \draw[thick](1,5)--(15,5)--(15,18.8);
\draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- (17,0);
\draw[ultra thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,20);
%% the co-ordinates -- major
\foreach \x in {0,2,...,16} {     % for x-axis
\draw [thick] (\x,0.2) -- (\x,-0.2);
} 
\foreach \y in {0,2,...,19} {   %% for y-axis
\draw [thick] (0.2,\y) -- (-0.2,\y);
}
\node [anchor=north] at (8,21) {{\Large{A graph of $x $ against $\frac{x^2}{y}$}}};
\node [anchor=north] at (0,-0.3) {0};
\node [anchor=east] at (-0.4,13) {\Large{$x$(cm)}};
\node [anchor=south] at (1.9,4.2) {\Large{(2.5,12.5)}};
\node [anchor=south] at (16.2,18.2) {\Large{(37.5,47.0)}};
\node [anchor=south] at (9,-1.5) {\Large{$\frac{x^2}{y}$(cm)}};
\draw[thick](15,5.2)--(14.8,5.2)--(14.8,5);
\node [anchor=north] at (2,-0.3) {5};\node [anchor=north] at (0,-0.3) {0};
\node [anchor=north] at (4,-0.3) {10};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,2) {5};
\node [anchor=north] at (6,-0.3) {15};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,4) {10};
\node [anchor=north] at (8,-0.3) {20};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,6) {15};
\node [anchor=north] at (10,-0.3) {25};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,8) {20};
\node [anchor=north] at (12,-0.3) {30};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,10) {25};
\node [anchor=north] at (14,-0.3) {35};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,12) {30};
\node [anchor=north] at (16,-0.3) {40};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,14) {35};
\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,0) {0};\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,16) {40};
\node [anchor=east] at (-0.3,18) {45};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that you can mark up stuff as code by putting `\`\`\`` in the lines above and below the code, just as I did for you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by "indicating the points on a graph when an interval"? Are you referring to the circled points in your graph?

Comment: am referring to the x -axis and y-axis.Take an example  0.1,0.2,0.3,---..For such a case the interval is 0.1 ,so how can i generate them on the axes automatically

Answer (score 3):

I think that the OP asks if there is an easier way to plot the points on this graph. If this is the question then the answer is yes: the code below replaces your six nested `\foreach` loops for these points with the single loop over a comma separated list of points:

```
\foreach \pt in {(4,8), (6,10), (8,12), (10.1,14), (12.1,16), (14.1,18) } {
  \draw \pt circle (0.15cm);
  \fill \pt circle (0.05cm);
}
```

More than this, however, I think that the code in the OP is unnecessarily complicated and that the resulting graph is very hard to read. The background blue grid dominates the graph, so if you really want this then I recommend making the grid more subdued by reducing the insensitivity of the colour from `blue!80` to `blue 30`, or even `blue!20`. I would also print the grid only in the positive quadrant so that it does not obscure your labels. The line through the the data points in the OP is thin and very hence very hard to read, so I would make it thick and in red Finally, using a `node` command you can add the labels on  the `x` and `y` axes when you draw the ticks. This simplifies your code significantly and leads to:

[image]

This said, wouldn't it be simpler to [pgfplpots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplpots)? As it says in the [TikZ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZ) manual

> If you are looking for an easy way to create a normal plot of a function with scientific axes, ignore this section and instead look at the pgfplots package or at the datavisualization command from Part VI.

Using [pgfplpots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplpots) most of the effort goes into the axis command to define the grid (see, for example, [Millimetric grid under PGFPlots graph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398396/millimetric-grid-under-pgfplots-graph)). The code simplifies even further and, ignoring the labels you are left with:

[image]

Here is the code that produces both of these plots:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\width{6}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\hauteur{12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, transform shape,
      help lines/.style={color=blue!30}]
    \foreach \step/\thick in {5cm/ultra thick, 1cm/thick, 2mm/thin} {
      \draw[\thick,step=\step,help lines] (0,0) grid (17,20);
    }
    % Draw axes
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (17,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,20);
    \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \X using {int(2.5*\x)}] in {0,2,...,16} {     % for x-axis
        \draw[thick] (\x,0.2) -- ++(0,-0.4)node[below]{$\X$};
    }
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \Y using {int(\y*2.5)}] in {0,2,...,19} {   %% for y-axis
        \draw[thick] (0.2,\y) -- ++(-0.4,0) node[left]{$\Y$};
    }
    % draw points
    \draw[red,thick](0,4)--(16,19.78);
    \foreach \pt in {(4,8), (6,10), (8,12), (10.1,14), (12.1,16), (14.1,18) } {
      \draw \pt circle (0.15cm);
      \fill \pt circle (0.05cm);
    }
    \draw[thick](1,5)--(15,5)--(15,18.8);
    \draw[thick](15,5.2)--(14.8,5.2)--(14.8,5);
    % labels
    \node [anchor=north] at (8,21) {\Large A graph of $x $ against $\frac{x^2}{y}$};
    \node [anchor=east] at (-0.4,13) {\Large{$x$(cm)}};
    \node [anchor=south] at (1.9,4.2) {\Large{(2.5,12.5)}};
    \node [anchor=south] at (16.2,18.2) {\Large{(37.5,47.0)}};
    \node [anchor=south] at (9,-1.5) {\Large{$\frac{x^2}{y}$(cm)}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-0.2,
        xmax=40,
        ymin=-0.2,
        ymax=45,
        minor x tick num=9,
        minor y tick num=9,
        xtick distance=5,
        ytick distance=5,
        grid=both,
        grid style={help lines},
        major grid style={blue!30, thick},
        minor grid style={blue!30,thin},
        axis line style={thick, blue!50},
      ]
      \addplot[red, thick, domain=0:40] plot (\x, x+10);
      \addplot[mark=o] coordinates {
        (10,20) (15,25) (20,30) (25.25,35) (30.25,40) (35.25,45)
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

With these changes in place

Comment: May I suggest `\addplot [red, thick, samples at={0,40}] {x+10};` for the first `\addplot`, and perhaps `only marks` for the second? I also wonder if the OP intended for the circled dots to be placed on the line itself, in which case `\addplot [mark=o, only marks, samples at={10,15,...,35}] {x+10};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. If this were a straight line plot then I'd agree but the OP plots these six points, with explicit coordinates, and they don't quite sit on the line. To be honest, I do not understand what is being plotted here are these are supposed to be points `(x,x^2/y)`.

Comment: `(x^2/y, x)` actually, but I don't understand that part either. I thought perhaps `\addplot [mark=o, only marks, samples at={10,15,...,35}] {x+10};` was what was meant by "indicate point on graph with a given interval", i.e. add markers to the plotted line at given intervals, but some clarification from the OP would help.

Comment: That is very good ,but also what of labelling the points in the intervals of 5,10,15 because the process was very long

Comment: @kazibastephen What do you mean by "labelling the points in the intervals of 5,10,15"?

Comment: \foreach \x in {0,5,...,40} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,-0.3) {\x}; } like when am using this command it spaces digits in an interval of  1 ,(0,1,2,3,4,5) yet i wanted in intervals of  5 .(0,5,10,15,20).

Comment: @kazibastephen I don't see this in the OP anywhere, or in my reply. It should not happen. Btw, if you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).