Scatter plot with discontinuity

I have a lot of these scatter plots to produce. I am not able to get the discontinuity correct on both axes an line up labels on both axes My MWE
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % grid
        \draw[     thin,brown!25]   (0,0) grid[step= 1mm] ++ (8,9);
        \draw[semithick,brown!50]   (0,0) grid[step= 5mm] ++ (8,9);
        \draw[    thick,brown!75]   (0,0) grid[step=10mm] ++ (8,9);
        % axis
        \draw[black, thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment length=2mm, amplitude=5pt}] (-0,0) -- (0.25,0);
        \draw[black, thick,decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment length=3.5mm, amplitude=5pt}] (0,0.25) -- (0,0.5);
        \draw[-Stealth, very thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,9.5) node[below right] {$y$};
        \draw[-Stealth, very thick] (-0.1,0) -- (8.5, 0) node[below  left] {$x$};
        
    
        \begin{axis}[
            at={(5,120)},
            anchor=south west,
            width=80mm,
            height=60mm,
            xmin=5, % Set the minimum x value
            xmax=13, 
            ymin=120, 
            ymax=14, % Adjust the maximum y value if needed
            xtick={6,7,...,13}, % Customize x-ticks starting at 6
            ymin=120, % Set the minimum y value
            ymax=210, % Set the maximum y value
            ytick={130,140,...,210},
            axis lines=middle,
            enlargelimits=false,
            grid=none, % Disable the default grid in the axis environment
            ]
            \addplot[
            only marks, % Use only marks to create a scatter plot
            mark=x, % Use crosses as markers
            mark size=2.5pt, % Adjust the size of the crosses
            ] coordinates {
                (6,155) (7,150) (7,165) (8,175) (8.5,170)
            };
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

    
\end{document}


With this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398396/millimetric-grid-under-pgfplots-graph

With this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110842/mike, you can use pure tikz or pgfplots. With pgfplots, there are only two grids, the 3rd can be drawn with \pgfplotsinvokeforeach
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    minor grid style={thin,brown!25},
    major grid style={thick,brown!75},
    every minor tick/.style={draw=none},
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    % style for middle grid
    middle grid style/.style={semithick,brown!50}
]
    \begin{axis}[
        at={(5,120)},
        anchor=south west,
        width=80mm,
        height=60mm,
        xmin=5, % Set the minimum x value
        xmax=13, 
        ymin=120, 
        ymax=14, % Adjust the maximum y value if needed
        xtick={5,6,7,...,13}, % Customize x-ticks starting at 6
        ymin=120, % Set the minimum y value
        ymax=210, % Set the maximum y value
        ytick={120,130,140,...,210},
        axis lines=middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
        %grid=none, % Disable the default grid in the axis environment
        grid=both,
        minor x tick num=9,
        minor y tick num=9,
        ]
        \addplot[
        only marks, % Use only marks to create a scatter plot
        mark=x, % Use crosses as markers
        mark size=2.5pt, % Adjust the size of the crosses
        ] coordinates {
            (6,155) (7,150) (7,165) (8,175) (8.5,170)
        };
        % 
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{5.5,6.5,...,12.5}{
            \draw[middle grid style]
                    (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
                    (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
        }
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{125,135,...,205}{
            \draw[middle grid style]
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1) --
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#1);}
    \end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


EDIT: f we want to plot the axes with tikz:
we put axis line style={opacity=0}
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
    minor grid style={thin,brown!25},
    major grid style={thick,brown!75},
    every minor tick/.style={draw=none},
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    % style for middle grid
    middle grid style/.style={semithick,brown!50}
]
    \begin{axis}[
        at={(5,120)},
        clip=false,%<-- to see decorate
        anchor=south west,
        width=80mm,
        height=60mm,
        xmin=5, % Set the minimum x value
        xmax=13, 
        ymin=120, 
        ymax=14, % Adjust the maximum y value if needed
        xtick={5,6,7,...,13}, % Customize x-ticks starting at 6
        ymin=120, % Set the minimum y value
        ymax=210, % Set the maximum y value
        ytick={120,130,140,...,210},
        axis lines=middle,
        axis line style={opacity=0},%<-- added
        enlargelimits=false,
        %grid=none, % Disable the default grid in the axis environment
        grid=both,
        minor x tick num=9,
        minor y tick num=9,
        ]
        \addplot[
        only marks, % Use only marks to create a scatter plot
        mark=x, % Use crosses as markers
        mark size=2.5pt, % Adjust the size of the crosses
        ] coordinates {
            (6,155) (7,150) (7,165) (8,175) (8.5,170)
        };
        % 
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{5.5,6.5,...,12.5}{
            \draw[middle grid style]
                    (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) --
                    (#1,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
        }
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{125,135,...,205}{
            \draw[middle grid style]
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#1) --
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#1);}
        %
    \draw[-Stealth,very thick]   (4.9,120)--
                        (5.1,120)--
                        (5.2,118)--
                        (5.4,122)--
                        (5.5,120)--
                        (13.6, 120) node[below] {$x$}; 
    \draw[-Stealth,very thick]   (5,119)--
                        (5,121)--
                        (5.1,123)--
                        (4.9,125)--
                        (5,126)--
                        (5, 216) node[left] {$y$};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


